# How to export the output of a SQL query to Excel using PowerShell?

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a script which pulls data from a SQL database and gives the o/p in excel but the o/p comes under single column. I want to have it in different colums. This is my script:

```
     $SQLServer = ""
     $SQLDBName = ""
     $SqlQuery = ""
     $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
     $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
     $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
     $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
     $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
     $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
     $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
     $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
     $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
     $DataSet.Tables[0] | out-file "C:\Users\sql.csv"
```

I also tried this script:

```
    $SQLServer = ""
    $SQLDBName = ""
    $SqlQuery = "select request_number,actioneer,audited_date from form_submission where actioneer ='XXXX' AND audited_date between '2020-05-19 00:00:00:000' and '2020-05-19 19:16:00:000';"| | Select @{n='request_number';e={request_number}}, @{n='actioneer';e={actioneer}} ,@{n ='audited_date';e={audited_date}}
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = 
    $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

    $DataSet.Tables[0] | out-file "C:\Users\sql.csv"
```

But this leads to the following error:

```
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Must declare the scalar variable "@"."
At C:\Users\sraghur\Documents\sql powershell.ps1:12 char:1
+ $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

Comment: Perhaps use Invoke-SqlCmd instead and assign its output to a variable that can be piped to a CSV file, or use the Text to Columns feature in Excel to split the data into columns based on a delimiter in the results?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, my test export created a standard CSV. Without seeing the query and/or actual data, it's just a guessing game.

Comment: check Read-SqlTable and this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171372/export-datatable-to-excel-using-powershell

Answer (score 2):

Is it really necessary to use .net methods instead of "Invoke-Sqlcmd"?
I usually use something like

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $strSQLServer -Database $strDatabase -QueryTimeout 180 -ConnectionTimeout 180 -query "select sqlcolumn1, sqlcolumn2, sqlcolumn3 from xxx" `
| Select-Object -Property sqlcolumn1, sqlcolumn2, sqlcolumn3 `
| Export-Csv "C:\Temp\SQLOutput.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

(You might have to install [powershell module "SqlServer"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/sql-server-powershell) beforehand)
On the other hand: Depending on the delimiter char used, the method of opening the file in Excel might be the problem: Restart Excel and choose "File > Open > ..." instead of double-clicking.
In case both doesn't work, you could also select - as LordPupazz recommended - the "single column" you were talking about and use "data > text to columns" (+ choose the correct delimiter).

Comment: Please see the edited version of my original post for the error im receiving

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Import-Module -Name SqlServer -Force

#Download ImportExcel Module if you don't have it already: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0
Import-Module -Name "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ImportExcel\ImportExcel.psm1" -force

##########################################################################################################################################################################################
#Create Excel File in Temp
##########################################################################################################################################################################################
$Folder = "C:\Temp";
$ReportName = "ReportName";

#$FileNameCSV = $Folder + "\" + $ReportName + ".csv"
$FileNameExcel = $Folder + "\" + $ReportName +"_"+ $(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy) + ".xlsx"  

#$TestPath1 = Test-Path -Path $FileNameCSV;
$TestPath2 = Test-Path -Path $FileNameExcel;

#If($TestPath1 -eq $true){Remove-Item -Path $FileNameCSV -Force -ErrorAction Ignore};
If($TestPath2 -eq $true){Remove-Item -Path $FileNameExcel -Force -ErrorAction Ignore};

##########################################################################################################################################################################################
#Connect to SQL and load report table to PS variable
##########################################################################################################################################################################################
#Variables for your source SQL Server information
$SqlServer = "sqlserver.domain,port"
$SQLDB = "main"
$SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbo.FOO"

#Wrap everything into a PS variable
$SQLProc = @{
    ServerInstance =  ""
    Database = ""
    Query = ""
}

#Set PS variable values
$SQLProc.ServerInstance = $SqlServer
$SQLProc.Database = $SQLDB
$SQLProc.Query = $SQLQuery

#Run SQL Query
$Results = Invoke-Sqlcmd @SQLProc


##########################################################################################################################################################################################
##Load data to Excel file on the specified Excel tab
##########################################################################################################################################################################################
#From the results dataset, select what columns you want in the Excel File
$Export = $Results | Select Column1,Column2,Column3
$Export | Export-Excel -Path $FileNameExcel -WorkSheetname "SheetName" -TableName "SQLData" -TableStyle Medium15 -AutoSize -BoldTopRow
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PowerShell already, why not to try [dbatools.io](https://dbatools.io/commands/) and [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/tree/master/Examples).

dbatools will help you to get data from the SQL with an easy way. Here is an example (for more check [my series about dbatools](https://www.bronowski.it/blog/2020/07/dbatools-io-command-line-sql-server-management-studio-connect-and-query/):

```
$data = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance "localhost,1433" -Query "SELECT name,database_id from sys.databases"
```

The other will help you to get CSV exported to the XLSX.

```
$data | Export-Excel -Path HowToExcel.xlsx -Show
```

See [how to use ImportExcel](https://www.bronowski.it/blog/2020/06/powershell-into-excelimportexcel-module-part-1/) on my blog too