# How to paste unspecified number of rows and columns from SQL Server to Excel worksheets

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

It has been a while since I have created VBA macros. Need to export multiple tables from SQL server into an Excel workbook. Some of the SQL query solutions for VBA use username/password combos, the SQL Server I am using is Microsoft authentication as the sign in.

I am currently getting errors when I try to paste from SQL Server with an unspecified range to a worksheet using `Range("A1").pastespecial`. Don't need the full solution, just the pieces that will help me get to where I need to be if possible. Thanks! The current solution I have requires copying tables manually from SQL.

```vb
Sub Format_Data_for_AddData()
'
' Format_Data_for_AddData Macro
' Add data copied to clipboard to a workbook, formatting cells to text, changing sheet name
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
Dim prevSheet As Worksheet 'Previous sheet to paste data into after
Dim activeBook As Workbook 'Active workbook being pasted into


    'Set current sheet to previous sheet
    Set prevSheet = ActiveSheet
    'Format cells to text
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    'Set current sheet to previous sheet
    Set prevSheet = ActiveSheet
    Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: "when I try to paste from sql server" - sql server is a database platform, not a specific graphical user interface, so where exactly are you copying from?

Comment: I am getting the runtime error '1004' PasteSpecial method of Range class failed.

Comment: sorry I should elaborate Tim, I am copying the data tables in sql server management studios after running about 30 select queries to an excel workbook

Comment: How about using the export wizard of sql server management studio? Right click on the database and in the context menu select Tasks -> Export Data. As Data Source select something like SQL Server Native Client and as Destination MS Excel. The rest should me more or less self explanatory.

Comment: Is there any value in considering PowerQuery instead of VBA to Poka-yoke the problem?

Comment: If you don't have to use VBA and can use PowerShell, the Import-Excel module can do this with a few lines.  https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.4.2

Comment: If you need to query the data from powershell, then look at DBATools.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62152323/how-to-export-the-output-of-a-sql-query-to-excel-using-powershell (This example does not use the modules I reference..)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to using VBA that's a lot easier.  This short and fully working example in PowerShell loads the data, creates the excel document, and opens it for display.  Search online for the DBATools and Import-Excel modules installs for details.

```
$cmsServer = 'myserver'
$query = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.ad_servers'
$dataSet = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $cmsServer -Database 'CMS' -Query $query
$dataSet | 
    Select-Object OperatingSystem, LastLogonEstimate | 
    Export-Excel -Path 'c:\temp\myreport.xlsx' -AutoSize -WorksheetName 'SampleExport' -ClearSheet -Show
```

If you want to import more than one table into the same document, call Export-Excel with the same document and a different worksheet name. Use Show only on the last call if you want the document to open.  (The document needs to be closed while it's updated.)

```
$dataSet1 | 
    Select-Object Col1, Col2 | 
    Export-Excel -Path 'c:\temp\myreport.xlsx' -AutoSize -WorksheetName 'Data Set 1' -ClearSheet
$dataSet2 | 
    Select-Object Col1, Col2 | 
    Export-Excel -Path 'c:\temp\myreport.xlsx' -AutoSize -WorksheetName 'Data Set 2' -ClearSheet
$dataSet3 | 
    Select-Object Col1, Col2, Col3 | 
    Export-Excel -Path 'c:\temp\myreport.xlsx' -AutoSize -WorksheetName 'Data Set 3' -ClearSheet -Show
```

If there are formatting issues, there are parameters other than AutoSize that might help.  For example, Numberformat.

ClearSheet will clear the worksheet if it already exists.  It's not need for a new document.